# Split string by brackets PHP

Tags: php, regex

Hey guys I have multiple strings which are similar in some way,
In general they always looks like:

Some text: `A3/S3 07/08-03/13 (8P)` 
Multiple brackets with textinside: `[V][S][3D][IRE][44]`

So full example are:

```
A3/S3 07/08-03/13 (8P) [V] [S] [3D] [IRE] [44]
or
A4 allroad/RS4 od 11/11 (8K) [V] [S] [3D] [IRE] [74]
```

I need to "parse it" to some array or object which will looks like:

```
array(
  [0] = "A3/S3 07/08-03/13 (8P)"
  [1] = "V" 
  [2] = "S"
  [3] = "3D"
  [4] = "IRE"
  [5] = "74"
)
```

I try to explode atleast that first text from rest with something like:

```
            $part = explode(") ", $name);
            echo $part[0];
```

unfortunately this just return `A3/S3 07/08-03/13 (8P` so without last bracket and even without that values in [ ] I'm a bit lost in this, is there a chance someone can help me?

Comment: that's normal. `explode()` doesn't include the chars you split on in the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
$s = 'A3/S3 07/08-03/13 (8P) [V] [S] [3D] [IRE] [44]';
$arr = preg_split('/\h*[][]/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r( $arr );
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => A3/S3 07/08-03/13 (8P)
    [1] => V
    [2] => S
    [3] => 3D
    [4] => IRE
    [5] => 44
)
```

Regex: `\h*[][]` is splitting on 0 or more horizontal space using `\h*` followed by either `[` or `]`